# Why the compiler allow to create an object of non static class in static context?

Tags: c#

As per the definition 
Non static things can not be accesses in static context
then how does it allow to create an object of non-static class to the static main method.

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base x = new Derived();
        x.Foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand that completely wrong. Static methods can't access the instance members, because they don't have the `this` reference. That isn't a prohibition, simply a fact of a missing reference. If you supply the reference (eg. through method parameter, creating an instance inside etc.), there's nothing to stop you from doing the call.

In other words,

```
class Test
{
  int testField = 23;

  static int GetTestField()
  {
    // Doesn't compile - static methods don't have a 
    // `this` reference to get the instance member
    return testField;
  }
}
```

Fails to compile. However,

```
public class Test
{
  public int testField = 23;
}

public static class Tester
{
  public static int GetTestField(Test test)
  {
    return test.testField;
  }
}
```

works just fine, because you pass the instance of `Test` you're trying to access.

You're not *forbidden* from using instance members in static methods (that would make them almost useless!). You just don't have a `this` reference, as simple as that.

Not really for Stack Overflow, but okay:

To understand this, it's helpful to know something of what's going under the hood. Basically, the CPU doesn't really have a notion of things like "classes" or "methods". That's why higher level programming languages invented calling conventions - common ways to invoke methods and pass them parameters. So, for example, if you wanted to call `Print(23);`, it might do something like this:

```
push 23
call Print
```

The `Print` method would then know it's parameter is store on top of the stack, and it could retrieve it using the current stack pointer, for example.

When classes came around, they brought a concept known as encapsulation. Basically, the class effectively has its own memory storage, and its own methods. When you want to access that data (or functionality), you have to do it through the class instance. On the lower level, this is usually handled by passing the reference to the object as the first parameter of the method. So, calling `test.GetTestField(23, 21)` (where `test` is a reference to an instance of the `Test` class) would do something like this:

```
push test
push 23
push 21
call Test.GetTestField
```

(this is all pseudo-code, the actual way the compiler handles that differs between calling conventions and languages; for example, parameters are often sent in reverse-order)

This way, the `GetTestField` method has access to the instance of the `Test` class (which it may or may not need for what it does). So when the method has to get the value of an instance field, for example, it can get `this.testField` (in C# and most other languages, the `this` can be ommited and is implied - everytime you access an instance field/method/etc. inside a class, it adds the `this` under the covers).

Static methods don't have this luxury - but that's also why they exist in the first place. They're used for functionality that is related to the class in which they are defined, but they don't require the instance members of the class (or they get the instance reference some other way).

Example - there's an `int` class in .NET framework (actually, it's a `struct`, but let's ignore that for now). The class has a couple of static methods, and a couple of instance methods. For example, the instance method `ToString()` takes the value of the int, and converts it to a string value - for this, it (obviously) needs to have the value of the integer. On the other hand, it has a static method `Parse(string)`, which takes a string parameter with the string value of the integer, and converts it to an integer. It creates a new integer, and parses the string value into it as an integer value. Since it creates a new instance of integer, it doesn't actually use `this`, and as such, can be safely declared as `static`. This avoids some extra costs of instance methods (even more so in languages where methods are virtual by default), at the very least, passing the extra parameter, but more importantly, it broadcasts the intent of the method - "I don't read or modify the instance members of this class". If you didn't have static methods, and you wanted to write the `Parse` method mentioned above, you'd have to create an instance of `int` first and call `Parse` on that.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on it because they don't have the this reference.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet I've edited my answer with some more information. However, do note that this is not a question for SO - it's basic knowledge in the programming language of your chosing. You should learn more about programming and the language, but SO is not the place for this - this site is about finding answers to specific problems, not wikipedia / a textbook :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right definition. Here is one from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and
>   events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance
>   variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method
>   parameter.

Note that you are not accessing nont-static members of `Test`, and neither you are using some outer variables.

Compare this, which is not allowed, to your snippet:

```
class Test
{
    int t = 1;

    static void Main()
    {
        Base x = new Derived();
        x.Foo(t); // not allowed!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make object of *non-static* `class` in static method but could not access the `non-static` member int that class. Suppose you have an object of Derived class as a member of Test then you wont be able to access that object in static method main.

Define a non-static method in Test class and try to call it from Main method you will get error again.

```
class Test
{
    Derived d = new Derived();
    static void Main()
    {
      // You can not access d here.
        // You can not access MyFun() here.
    }
    void MyFun()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remember that you are not accessing the `Foo()` directly but with the help of instance variable `x`.That is always possible.

**Note :** you can not access non static members as below:

```
void Foo()
{

}
static void Main()
{
   Foo();//compile error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely *can* access non-static members in a static context, as long as you have a valid reference to an object.

The only reason a static context is different from a non-static context in this regard, is that the static context doesn't have the `this` reference (which is implied when you access non-static members without explicitly referencing an object). The non-static context, on the other hand, always has an implicit `this` reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem  isn't that you can't access non-static fields/methods/etc in a static context, it's that you can't access non-static fields/methods without an instance.

In the code you provided, there *is* an instance of `Base`, and so you *can* access it's methods, regardless of the context.